# Derivative of composition of functions with inner function: $\frac{dg(f(x))}{df(x)}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How can we find derivative of composition of functions with inner function, as in this derivative?
 $\frac{dg(f(x))}{df(x)}$ .

This is what I have till now:
I know $\frac{dg(x)}{df(x)} = \frac{g'(x)}{f'(x)}$  So, $\frac{dg(f(x))}{df(x)} = \frac{g'(f(x))}{f'(x)}$. Can it be further simplified?

Comment: I think your expression is just a symbol for $g'(f(x))$

Comment: You could do $\frac{dg(f(x))/dx}{df(x)/dx} = \frac{g'(f(x))f'(x)}{f'(x)} = g'(f(x))$ provided the derivative of $f$ doesn't vanish